# Vector images not displayed in iOS Asset Catalog (Assets.xcassets) and, at the same time, new assets get an incomplete Contents.json file

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

My iOS Asset Catalog always worked as expected, but today when I open the Asset Catalog editor, none of the vector images are displayed in the editor, which they always were before. Just empty rectangles. The images still appear correctly when the app runs. PNG images are visible as usual.

At the same time, I now find today that when I create a new asset, the Contents.json file that is automatically created does not contain any filenames and then of course the new image does not appear when the app runs. (The asset does contain the right pdf images.) As a workaround, if I manually edit Contents.json to insert the following in the expected position, the new image does appear at runtime:

```
{
  "filename": "my button_1.pdf",
  "idiom": "iphone"
},
```

I get exactly the same results if I create a new Asset Catalog and perform the operations there. Deleting *.bin, *.obj did not help.

Unable to find anything posted on this - any suggestion welcomed.

Visual Studio for Mac V8.5
Xamarin Forms V4.5.0.495
MacOS 10.15.3
iOS V13.3.1
PNG images were created in Inkscape V0.92 on Windows10.

Comment: Hi , have a check with the property of Imgae whehter set correct action as follow :https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRxr.png

Comment: Thanks, Junior, but my images are in Assets.xcassets, not in Resources.

Comment: Okey , do you update VS or Forms recently ? I think you can check the last success is which version of VS and Forms . Then downgrading to that version to check whehter that also works .

Comment: Good suggestion, JJ. Will try that when I get a chance.